# SVD maps from orthogonal basis of rowspace to orthogonal basis in column space?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I've been going through the MIT OpenCourseWare Linear Algebra course, and I've been understanding it until early in the [Singular Value Decomposition video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nx0lRBaXoz4).

The Professor says (and I'm paraphrasing) starting at the 3:12 mark of the video: "You remember the picture of a linear transformation.  A typical vector $v_1$ in the rowspace gets mapped to some vector in the column space, say $u_1 = Av_1$.  What I'm looking for in an SVD is an orthogonal basis in the row space that gets mapped to an orthogonal basis in the column space."

I don't understand the "$v_1$ is a vector in the rowspace" part.  For example, if $A$ is a 3x3 matrix of all 1's, then the rowspace is just the line through $<1,1,1>$ while $v_1$ can be any vector.  In that case $v_1$ is certainly not in the rowspace.

Can someone provide better intuition for what SVD is doing geometrically?

Comment: He's just assuming $v_1$ belongs to the row space.  In Gilbert Strang's "four subspaces" picture, we see that the row space of $A$ is the orthogonal complement of the null space of $A$.  Any vector $v$ can be decomposed as $v = v_1 + v_2$, where $v_1$ is in the row space and $v_2$ is in the null space.  Then $Av = A v_1 + A v_2 = A v_1$.  So the part of $v$ that belongs to the null space has no effect when we compute $Av$.  So when we think about $A$, we only need to understand what $A$ does to the row space.  (And $A$ actually provides an isomorphism from the row space to column space.)

Comment: Why do you think $v_1$ can be any vector in SVD? If the row space is just a line through $<1,1,1>$ then $v_1=\pm <1,1,1>$, appropriately scaled to have length $1$. $u_1 = A v_1$. So $u_1=\pm <1,1,1>$, which is in the column space. The only problem is that $u_1$ must also be a unit vector so you need to add a scale factor: $\sigma_1 u_1 = A v_1$.
The SVD without including the null space is:
$$A = \left(\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{3}}(1, 1, 1)'\right) 3 \left(\frac{\pm1}{\sqrt{3}}(1, 1, 1)\right)$$